# wsdl link getting folder added to path

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, wsdl, ria

I am playing with WCF RIA services for the first time and have a problem with my service when uploaded to my hosted website. When I run locally (had to remove http:// from all links as I'm a new user) localhost:50365/DocumentService.svc I get the wsdl link localhost:50365/DocumentService.svc?wsdl which is exactly right, however when hosted the path example.com/documentservice.svc the wsdl link is shown as example.com/mydomain/documentservice.svc which doesn't work. Removing the example folder to get www.mydomain.co.uk/documentservice.svc?wsdl returns me the wsdl correctly. What setting am I missing in the WCF setup for this additional folder to get added? Obviously it means the web service isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you have to move service from root of the website to the `mydomain` Web Application. This configurations you can do using inetmgr.

Comment: Thanks, but its just a simple hosted website, no access to IIS. Was hoping it was configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running into this [MSDN support issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971842) in your hosted service. You may not need to apply the hotfix if you're running a .NET 4 WCF service.